# How to add www when string already contains Http

Tags: php

How to add www to the url if there isn't a www and the string is named or https://example.com ?

Example:

```
http://ellos.dk //should be http://www.ellos.dk
```

I know this might be rather basic but i cant seem to find a pretty solution

Comment: concatenation with substrings, str_replace(), parse_url() then http_build_url(), there's a whole host of options for something as basic as this

Comment: Just let me point out that www. is not *necessary* per se and the URL may actually not work if you add it. example.com and www.example.com are two different domains.

Comment: @deceze depends on the DNS setup for the site.

Comment: @Pitch Exactly, that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a "negative lookahead" in regex:

```
$url = preg_replace('#^(https?)://(?!www\.)#i', '$1://www.', $url);
```

[**Regex 101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/kU6gP6)

PHP code:

```
<?php
    function addWWW($url) {
        return preg_replace('#^(https?)://(?!www\.)#i', '$1://www.', $url);
    }

    var_dump( addWWW('http://ellos.dk') );
    var_dump( addWWW('http://www.ellos.dk') );
    var_dump( addWWW('https://www.ellos.dk') );
    var_dump( addWWW('https://ellos.dk') );
    var_dump( addWWW('HTTP://ellos.dk') );
?>
```

Which will output:

```
string(19) "http://www.ellos.dk"  
string(19) "http://www.ellos.dk"  
string(20) "https://www.ellos.dk"  
string(20) "https://www.ellos.dk"  
string(19) "HTTP://www.ellos.dk"
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/69339)

**PLEASE NOTE**: An url such as `http://subdomain.ellos.dk` would turn into `http://www.subdomain.ellos.dk`.

Comment: `preg_replace('/^(https?):\/\/(?!www\.)/', '$1://www.', $url);` Might be better.

Comment: @BenFortune It's funny you posted that - I was in the middle of changing my code for exactly that! :)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the `www` is *never* there:

```
str_replace('://', '://www.', 'http://ellos.dk');
```

If the `www` might be there you will have to had some validation to determine if you need to call the code above. But that will handle putting the `www` in place inside the string.

Comment: You can remove protocol from your test, maybe he will have some ftp links. URLs can't contain '://' string except after protocol. So we can reduce it to `str_replace('://', '://www.', 'http://ellos.dk');`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to achieve this:

```
function addWWW($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if (strpos($url, '://www') === FALSE) {
        return 'http://www.'.$parts['host'];
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo addWWW('http://ellos.dk');
echo addWWW('http://www.ellos.dk');
```

Output:

```
http://www.ellos.dk
http://www.ellos.dk
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/69342)

Comment: Using [http_build_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) to recreate would be cleaner

Comment: @MarkBaker: It may not be present on all PHP installations, so didn't include it.

Answer (score 2):

To add some validation:

```
function addwww($link) {
    if(strpos($link,'://www') === false) {
        return str_replace('://','://www',$link);
    }
    return $link;
}
```